# How can i store objects in local file?

Tags: javascript, file, fetch, local, store

I'm creating an quiz.
In the page, user can add a question to the quiz.
How can i simple save these new questions in local file? 
I would like to have it the next time I launch the page...

I've tried with fetch POST request, but i got 405 error..

the GET request works fine..

```
fetch('./questions.json', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'dean',
        login: 'dean',
    })
})
.then(function (data) {
    console.log('Request success: ', data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Request failure: ', error);
});

fetch('./questions.json').then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error('Request failed! ');
})
.then((Jsondata) => {
    console.log(Jsondata[0])
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message)
});
```

What am i doing wrong with fetch POST request?
What is the best option to store info which users add? 
Why local json file doesn't work? maybe should i use external JSON file?

I'll be so glad if u could help me...

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is a javascript variable that acts like a dictionary variable (key-value pair), In the above code, 'responseData' is key for your data storage location.
The setItem function used to save the data in a temp location as you clear the cache the data will remove.
To get the value from the key getItem function is used. That we are again storing in variable resData.

```
    //storing temp data
    localStorage.setItem('responseData',data);
    //featching temp data
    var resData = localStorage.getItem('responseData');
```